# Show that a statistical model belongs to exponential family

Tags: statistics, exponential-function

I have this statistical model:

$$f_{j,k}(y)=\frac{\sqrt{j}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{\sqrt{jk}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}} \text{exp}\left( -\frac{1}{2} (j y + \frac{k}{y}) \right) \quad \quad y>0$$

In this case the parameters j and k are unknown.

My question is, why is this model a part of the exponential family?

Answer (score 1):

A family of distributions is said to belong to a vector exponential family if the probability density function can be written as
$$
f_{\pmb{\theta}}(x) =h(x) \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \eta_i(\pmb{\theta}) T_i(x) - A(\pmb{\theta}) \right)= h(x) \exp\left(\pmb{\eta}(\pmb{\theta})\cdot \pmb{T}(x) - A(\pmb{\theta}) \right)
$$
or in the alternative, equivalent form 
$$
f_{\pmb{\theta}}(x) =h(x)g(\pmb{\theta}) \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \eta_i(\pmb{\theta}) T_i(x)  \right)= h(x)g(\pmb{\theta}) \exp\left(\pmb{\eta}(\pmb{\theta})\cdot \pmb{T}(x)\right)
$$
The exponential family is said to be in canonical form if $\eta_i(\pmb{\theta})=\theta_i$, for all $i$.

In your case 
$$
f_{j,k}(y)=\frac{\sqrt{j}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{\sqrt{jk}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}} \text{exp}\left( -\frac{1}{2} (j y + \frac{k}{y}) \right) \quad \quad y>0
$$
that is an exponential family in canonical form with
$$
\begin{align}
\pmb{\theta}&=(j,k)\\
h(y)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}y^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
g(\pmb{\theta})&=g(j,k)=\sqrt{j}\,\operatorname{e}^{\sqrt{jk}}=\operatorname{e}^{-A(\pmb\theta)}\\
\pmb{\eta}(\pmb{\theta})&=\left(\eta_1(j,k),\eta_2(j,k)\right)=(j,k)=\pmb{\pmb\theta}\\
\pmb T(y)&=\left(T_1(y),T_2(y)\right)=\left(-\frac{y}{2},-\frac{1}{2y}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Great answer! But how will the function look like if rewrite my example into canonical form but keeps it as one function. (So we don't separate into h(y) etc.)

Comment: Are you aware of in the function of g, that $e^{ \sqrt{jk}}$ is $\text{exp} \left( \sqrt{jk} \right)$ ?